# Open maps activity from other activity with specific coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm currently creating an app which uses Google Maps API. Here's what I want to do:

I have got activity A. There is a button in activity A. When button is clicked, i want to open MapsActivtiy (no Google Maps app) at specific coordinates and zoom level. I was searching a lot in internet, but I couldn't find the answer.

Note that I also have activity B, activity C, activity D, etc. and each contains a button. And each button in each activity should open MapsActivity on different coordinates and zoom.

SOLUTION (i can't write answer and accept it beacuse question is closed)

In activtity A:

```
//onClick method
public void viewOnMap(View view)
{
    LatLng coords = new LatLng(50.191067, 18.452964);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("coords", coords);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In maps activtiy onMapReady()

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
LatLng coords = intent.getParcelableExtra("coords");

//some maps code etc...

if(coords != null)
    {
        if (coords.equals(some_coords_1))
        {
            LatLng coords_zoom = new LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude), 17));

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coords_zoom));
        }

        if(coords.equals(some_coords_2)
        {
           LatLng coords_zoom = new LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);

           googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude), 17));

           googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coords_zoom))

         }
```

Comment: Pass the coordinates and zoom level to your MapsActivity and use the moveCamera on the GoogleMap instance

Comment: @Alex it is easy for you, but I'm beginner and it's my second program. I'd be very happy if somebody would place some code.

Comment: You can't just copy paste an app from stackoverflow. I understand your struggle, but you should learn how to use a bundle and how to pass it to another activity. (beginner level stuff). Also using the moveCamera is a method and since you already have the map it's easy to apply it. Please don't wait for code.

Comment: @Alex OK i'll try to do it right. You gave me fishing rod, not the fish. Anyway thanks for help :)

Comment: @Baftek, this isn't a site where people generally write your code for you.  Give it a try, and if you run into specific problems, people will be happy to help fix errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside activity A:

Pass the coordinates in the Intent for the other activity.

```
 Button btnActivityB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);

    btnActivityB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);

              LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-20.65,-40.79) //Or any other value...

              intent.put("LatLng", latLng); 

              startActivity(intent);
          }
 });
```

Inside activity B:

Check if you received the Extras correctly. Then, after you initiate the Map, move the camera.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent.hasExtra("LatLng")){
            mLatLng = intent.getParcelableExtra("LatLng");

        }


public void onMapReady(){          
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: `LatLng` implements `Parcelable` so you don't need to pass two `double`s, you can directly pass `LatLng`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: But i have got many more activities, and buton in each other should open different view and zoom on map

Comment: You can do that to as many activities you want.
You can pass the zoom in the same way you passed the LatLng

Comment: @LeandroBorgesFerreira But my map always centers on the position given in last "moveCamera". I have also a problem with "cannot resolve symbol "mLatLng", because it's in other method(OnCreate)

Comment: mLatLng is not supposed local, it is supposed to be a variable of your activity. When exactly does this centers movement happens?

Comment: So where should I place Intent intent = getIntent()...? Under class, in OnCreate or in OnMapReady?

Comment: It's a good practice to try a little bit before asking... Anyway, update the mLatLng in the onCreate(), but declare LatLan mLatLng outside any mathod